# Why are we allowed to set both the disabled and selected attributes on <option>s at the same time?

Tags: html

Why are we allowed to set both the disabled and selected attributes on `<option>`s at the same time when their values will not get submitted to a server?

I was expecting to get some error is VS Code if I applied both the disabled and selected attributes on an `<option>`.

Comment: not all forms are used directly with servers, some provide UI. You can also pre-select a disabled option to force the user to change the default value in harmony with a form validation process.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it's allowed in VS Code [because the HTML specification allows it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element) (insofar as the HTML specification does not have any prohibitions on an `<option>` being both `disabled` and `selected`).

And I can think of at least two practical use-cases:

#### Use-case 1: User-instructional message or placeholder

The `<select>` element doesn't have the `placeholder=""` attribute that `<input />` and `<textarea>` have, so you can use a disabled `<option>` for some initial text *that cannot be selected as an actual option* by the user, like in this snippet:

Granted, the `selected` attribute isn't needed [when the `<option>` is the first item](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#placeholder-label-option), but I'd recommend rendering the `selected` attribute anyway, just-in-case something causes another `<option>` element to come before the faux-placeholder option.

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

#### Use-case 2: To represent mandatory options in a `<select multiple>`

```html
<label>
  <span>Car order options</span>
  <select multiple>
    <option disabled selected>Engine (required)</option>
    <option disabled selected>Seats (required)</option>
    <option>Elon Musk's ego</option>
    <option>Heated seats</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

...though as disabled options won't be included in the submitted `<form>` values, so server-side logic will need to infer/add those values to whatever internal processing happens.